# Making multiple "any" more efficient

Tags: python

I am using `any` to see if a string in a longer string (description) matches with any strings across several lists. I have the code working, but I feel like it's an inefficient way of doing a comparison, and would like feedback on how I can make it more efficient.

```
def convert_category(description):
    categoryFood = ['COUNTDOWN', 'BAKE', 'MCDONALDS', 'ST PIERRE', 'PAK N SAVE', 'NEW WORLD']
    categoryDIY = ['BUNNINGS', 'MITRE10']

    containsFood = any(keyword in description for keyword in categoryFood)
    containsDIY = any(keyword in description for keyword in categoryDIY)

    if(containsFood):
        return 'Food and Groceries'
    elif(containsDIY):
        return 'Home and DIY'
    return ''
```

Comment: Your approach seems reasonable. You could also return early if `containsFood` is true (and avoid creating `containsDIY` in that case).

Comment: For those tempted to use set intersection against description.split() note the spaces in food categories.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regular expression. They are optimized for this kind of problem - searching for any of multiple strings - and the hot part of the code is pushed into a fast library. With big enough strings you should notice the difference.

```py
import re

foodPattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape, categoryFood))
diyPattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape, categoryDIY))

containsFood = re.search(foodPattern, description) is not None
containsDiy = re.search(diyPattern, description) is not None
```

You can easily extend this with word boundary or similar features to make the keyword matching be smarter/only match whole words.

Comment: This won't be any faster, in fact it may be slower

Comment: Speed must depend on the input, which is very vaguely specified so far.

Comment: Python doesn't do any optimization to a regex, so (under the hood) its doing the same thing, just with the loops reversed (for every start position, try to match each pattern between alternations, as opposed to the any()/for way, which check for each pattern, is it present at any offset)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to make this faster is some negligible work to return some statements easier from the sounds of things. Marking as answered and closing.